# Need to add background to navbar in mobile mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, transparent, navbar

I need to make all navbar text/icon readable. By adding some color - white for example. To the navbar. I tried to search for the solutions here and there on google. But none of them works. I built this with bootstrap 3.0. Thing works just find in desktop mode but gone wild in mobile mode. The navbar's background gone transparent so it really heard to read the menu content.

As the image here:
[image]

As the image shown above. You can't even see what is what by the menu text. So I need these link painted with color instead of transparent. Do you guys have an idea how or which line to deal with.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could do something by editing the css and adding an override for mobile. This will allow you to change any css needed in the mobile version.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 /* put any styles needed */
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? If not, I can look closer if you would like!